# Is there a codeigniter auth class which allows facebook login?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication, login-script

Is there any codeigniter authentication class which allows to login using facebook or which is the best auth class for codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the project is still in development, but the A3M (Account Authentication & Authorization) module looks like it may be a good match for you. The CI forum thread is [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/144755/) and the google code page is [here](http://code.google.com/p/a3m/).

> Key features
>
> 1. Signin/Signup with Facebook, Twitter and OpenID (Google, Yahoo,
>      AOL, MySpace, Others)
> 2. Traditional Sign Up, Sign In (with remember me) and Sign Out
> 3. Manage Account/Profile Details (including Profile Picture)
> 4. Manage Linked Accounts
> 5. Forgot/Reset Password for native accounts
> 6. reCAPTCHA support
> 7. SSL support
> 8. Language file for i18n (plus all the necessary i18n tables, country,
>      language, ip to country, etc)
> 9. Semantic XHTML views

Answer (score 1):

I found this lib http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/ via CI forums, but never used it. It might be helpful.